# Can't restart thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-me

I have the following thread:

```
public void start() {
        isRunning = true;

        if (mainThread == null) {
            mainThread = new Thread(this);
            mainThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        }

        if (!mainThread.isAlive()) {
            try {
                mainThread.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

At some point I want to stop it's operation:

```
public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
        System.gc();
}
```

When calling `start()` again the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
```

Pointing the `mainThread.start()` line of code.

What is the best way to start/stop a thread? how can I make this thread reusable?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't let it finish - just loop around some wait() at the top.  When you want it to run, signal it.

Comment: Instead of just calling start(), type this: new Thread(this).start();

Answer (score 6):

Once a thread stop you **cannot restart** it in Java, but of course you can create a new thread in Java to do your new job.

The user experience won't differ even if you create a new thread or restart the same thread(this you cannot do in Java).

You can read the website for API specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

What you might be looking for is `Interrupts`. An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common for the thread to terminate.

To know more about interrupts read the Java tutorial guide http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 1):

From your code slice it seems that you are using a `Runnable` class with a `Thread` attribute. Instead of using stop/start you might use suspend/resume below:

```
private boolean isPaused;

public void run() {
    while (!isRunning) {
        // do your stuff
        while (isPaused) {
            mainThread.wait();
        }
    }
}

public void suspend() {
    isPaused = true;
}

public void resume() {
    isPaused = false;
    mainThread.notify();
}
```

I did not add the `synchronized` blocks to keep the code small, but you will need to add them.